# Move 1st layer key/val pair inside of another key in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

I need to move "Email_Tempc" "Id" and "Phone_Tempc" and their values inside of the Contact object inside arr1.

It currently looks like

```
let arr1 = [{
    Contact: {
        Name: "joe342 TEST CONTACT2"
    },
    Email_Tempc: "joe21@email.com2",
    Id: "a0X0n0000012fzuEAA",
    Phone_Tempc: "1234567890",
    Role_Tempc: "Contact"
}, {
    Contact: {
        Name: "TEST API CONTACT 8"
    },
    Email_Tempc: "test@email.com8",
    Id: "a0X0n0000012haIEAQ",
    Phone_Tempc: "1234567890",
    Role_Tempc: "Plan Administrator"
}
```

It should end up looking like

```
[{
    Contact: {
        Name: "joe342 TEST CONTACT2"
        Email_Tempc: "joe21@email.com2",
        Id: "a0X0n0000012fzuEAA",
        Phone_Tempc: "1234567890",
    },
    Role_Tempc: "Contact"
}, {
    Contact: {
        Name: "TEST API CONTACT 8",
        Email_Tempc: "test@email.com8",
        Id: "a0X0n0000012haIEAQ",
        Phone_Tempc: "1234567890",
    },
    Role_Tempc: "Plan Administrator"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job.

```js
let arr1 = [{
    "Contact": {
        "Name": "joe342 TEST CONTACT2"
    },
    "Email_Tempc": "joe21@email.com2",
    "Id": "a0X0n0000012fzuEAA",
    "Phone_Tempc": "1234567890",
    "Role_Tempc": "Contact"
}, {
    "Contact": {
        "Name": "TEST API CONTACT 8"
    },
    "Email_Tempc": "test@email.com8",
    "Id": "a0X0n0000012haIEAQ",
    "Phone_Tempc": "1234567890",
    "Role_Tempc": "Plan Administrator"
}];

arr1 = arr1.map(({ Contact, Email_Tempc, Id, Phone_Tempc, Role_Tempc }) => {
    return {
        Contact: {
            ...Contact,
            Email_Tempc,
            Id,
            Phone_Tempc,
        },
        Role_Tempc,
    };
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Even without a return `arr1 = arr1.map(({ Contact, Email_Tempc, Id, Phone_Tempc, Role_Tempc }) => ({ Contact: { ...Contact,  Email_Tempc, Id, Phone_Tempc }, Role_Tempc}));`